# How to ping a specific port

Tags: networking, software-recommendation, ping, diagnostic, packet-analyzer

I often use the `ping` command to check if a website is available or not, or if I can access a machine, so basically mostly for diagnostics, and what would be really useful is if I could specify which port(s) those ICMP echoes go to, is there any way of doing this with `ping`, or another tool which would allow for me to easily do this without having to generate packets manually?

An option for instance would be to create a custom ICMP packet set to go to a specific port, and then I could use `bittwist` to send it, and `Wireshark` to monitor if I am getting anything in return, but this seems a bit of a hassle to do every time, so I was wondering if there is an easier route?

Comment: There is no concept of "port" in ICMP. If you want to reach a TCP or UDP port, use `netcat`.

Comment: you can try with TCPPing or smokeping tools...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIRC you cannot send a "ping" packet to a specific port.

On a port, there is a "software" listening. This software will implement it's own protocol - HTTP, SMTP, FTP, or even some own protocol.

Those servers won't respond to an ICMP packet. ICMP packets need to be sent to the ICMP port.

However, you may just try to open a TCP connection (`telnet host 12345`) and see if the connection is successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to ping a specific IP-port on your network:

1. Download and install [nMap](https://nmap.org/).
2. Run `ifconfig -a` to identify your network topology; the terminal output should display the host IP-address traced to your command-line, displayed after "inet" (e.g. `inet: 10.0.0.2`).
3. Now open the nMap tool to scan your network by running `nmap -sP network-ip-address topology/24` (e.g. `nmap -sP 10.0.0.1/24`); that should display all hosts connected to the network.
4. Locate the host IP-address of the port you wish to ping; for example, if your network is hosting a VPN server on a router at IP address `10.0.0.233`.  First, try to ping the address by running `nmap -sn host-ip-address` (eg `nmap -sn 10.0.0.233`)- the terminal output should return a report that the server is either up or down.
5. However, sometimes a host may only be visible or identifiable if you ping a specific port by running `nmap -Pn port-number ip-address`; for example, the subject router may only be traceable if we ping a specific port on the router- in this case UDP port 1143 for OpenVPN (e.g. `nmap -Pn 1143 10.0.0.233`).  The aforementioned command should confirm that the port is open within the terminal output, even if the host is ostensibly down according to the initial run of the nmap port-scan.

Hope that helps- it helped me!